# Convert array of characters to array of ints c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, casting, character-encoding

I have an array of 10 numerical characters, and I want to convert it, index by index, to an array of ints. For instance, if array[0] = '2', I want to edit the array so that array[0] = 2.

How do I do this as part of a for loop? I was thinking something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 array[i] = array[i] - '0';
}
```

Please let me know if this is right, or if I need to change something. Thank you!

Comment: What is the question exactly? Is there a problem with your solution you need help with? If not, feedback requests for working code should be directed to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So when you ran it - did it work?  If it did, then why post; if it didn't, then what did your debugger tell you about it?

Comment: Or at least std::cout ? This seems trivially easy to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just change the type of an array. If the first array is a char array, you need to create a new array that would hold integers. Then index by index you need to convert the character from the first array to an integer and then store it in your new array.

```
 int intArray[10];
 char charArray[10]; 
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     intArray[i] = charArray[i] - '0';
  }
```

Comment: Typo:  `array[i]` --> `charArray[i]`

Answer (score 0):

The code above would not work as you are taking a `char` and trying to convert it to an `int` then place the `int` into the `char`. You should have another array for your `int[]`.